# Let a bot join a Microsoft teams call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I noticed there is no direct way to get the callers phone number from direct routing calls from the microsoft API. You can write a lissener but there is a delay of around 15 minutes.

I was looking through the documentation and was wondering if it's possible, when a user accepts a call, a bot joins in and retrieves the caller information of the user, so you receive this information in realtime.

Is there any way this is possible, or is there a way to receive the callers phone number in real time?

Comment: When a call is received, the bot can answer, reject, or redirect the call using the `/calls/{id}/answer`, `/calls/{id}/reject`, or `/calls/{id}/redirect` API endpoints respectively. The incoming call request can be an invite from a participant in a group call or a peer-to-peer call. If an invite to a group call is received, the notification contains the `chatInfo` and `meetingInfo` parameters. To retrieve the caller's phone number, you can use the `from` property of the call object. The `from` property contains the identity of the caller, which can include the phone number.

Comment: `var call = await graphClient.Calls["{callId}"].Request().GetAsync();                 
var callerPhoneNumber = call.From.PhoneNumber;`